# Invalid variable for Set LAS Class Codes Using Features in ModelBuilder of ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, arcgis-pro, extract, las

I am attempting the following process in Model Builder in ArcGIS Pro 2.5. I have an original .las file as input into Extract LAS. What I failed to mention initially is this is NOT LIDAR, this is LAS from UAS Photogrammetry. While I have completed the entire process I am about to describe without issue, manually, I am now having a lot of difficulty stringing these tools together.

When run alone, Extract LAS works, but I cannot work out how to string it into Set LAS Class Codes Using Features.  Even using 'Out' as a precondition, running the tool yields 'Parameters are not valid.  The value does not exist'.

From what I know, Extract LAS generates a new .las and a .lasd, however only the .lasd displays as output in Model Builder.  This is problematic for my next tool, because it seems Set LAS Class Codes Using Features only accepts a .las as input.  For example, it will accept my original .las file as input, but of course I want the output version that is generated from Extract LAS.

I have tried using Path and Name elements from Parse Path as input directly into Set Las Class Codes, I have tried creating a new variable from Path and Name to use as input, I have tried Calculate Values.  For each, I've tried every combination of stringing these elements together:  Name alone, Name with the .las extension, Path and Name, Path and Name with a .las extension, etc etc. but all are invalid input.  I have tried using 'Out' as a precondition.

Can anyone see what I need to do to string this together?

I've tried too many combinations to list here but here is one example.  Currently, the original .las input is turned on in my map.

---

After posting the above, I ran Extract LAS, then added the Set LAS Class Codes Using Features Tool and navigated directly to the new Extracted .las file I needed as input.  When I re-ran the model, it set the Input LASD Dataset as a Precondition (shown at bottom) and this worked.  I am positive when I tried this, on my own, the model still threw the error indicating the vale did not exist.

Is there some trick to setting preconditions that I might be missing?

Even more, now that I have a Reclassified LAS Dataset, the next tool now will not let me connect to it as the next input, nor will the LAS to Multipoint tool let me input any of my LAS files even in a new model when LAS To Multipoint is the only tool.  The only options for input seem to be the Output Folders from the first step, or to set the Reclassified Dataset as an Extent or Precondition when I try to connect it with an arrow.  I can only add the LAS as input if I manually navigate to a folder and select it.

Is there no way to input my individual LAS file as input from within ModelBuilder, or must I put the Reclassified LAS output into it's own folder in order to connect it to LAS to Multipoint?

[image]
[image]
[image: Cannot input Reclassified LAS Dataset as an input]